# Envoy Large http2_protocol_options initial_stream_window_size causes send/read timeout on ALB/nginx upstream on large responses and slow clients

Tags: envoyproxy

We use Envoy as an edge proxy, in front of an AWS ALB with a default  idle_timeout.timeout_seconds of 60 seconds, and were having some reports of clients downloads in browser failing around the 150 MB mark.

Unfortunately the envoy logs just showed:
   response_duration: -
   response_ttfb: -
   flags: -

and a 200 OK

We were able to recreate the problem in browsers by limiting our connection speed to ~1 MB/s.

We noted the problem only occurred with HTTP2.

Looking at Firefox about:networking traces we observed that a HTTP2 rst_stream with 0 error code was being sent:

```
2019-08-29 22:09:46.217000 UTC - [Parent 12304: Socket Thread]: I/nsHttp Http2Session::RecvRstStream 0000019A3D1FB000 RST_STREAM Reason Code 0 ID 11
```

We enabled traces on envoy and saw the stream was begin paused and resumed like so:

```
{"time": "2019-08-30 09:30:48.432", "level": "debug", "type": "http2", "message": "[source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:200] [C213] send buffer under limit "}
{"time": "2019-08-30 09:30:48.432", "level": "debug", "type": "http", "message": "[source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:1607] [C213][] Enabling upstream stream due to downstream stream watermark."}
```

We did a packet capture on envoy and found that around ~250 MB was read from the ALB then followed by a 60+ second pause where envoy set the receive window to 0 while the client kept reading slowly:

```
09:29:45.795071 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], seq 331920955:331922379, ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58414411 ecr 2277140227], length 1424
09:29:45.795088 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], seq 331922379:331924715, ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58414411 ecr 2277140227], length 2336
09:29:45.834615 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331924715, win 2, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277140419 ecr 58414410], length 0
09:29:46.356500 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [P.], seq 331924715:331925739, ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58414552 ecr 2277140419], length 1024
09:29:46.356523 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277140941 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:29:46.900379 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58414688 ecr 2277140941], length 0
09:29:46.900397 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277141485 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:29:47.796392 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58414912 ecr 2277141485], length 0
09:29:47.796413 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277142381 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:29:49.428395 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58415320 ecr 2277142381], length 0
09:29:49.428410 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277144013 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:29:52.660486 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58416128 ecr 2277144013], length 0
09:29:52.660501 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277147245 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:29:58.804579 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58417664 ecr 2277147245], length 0
09:29:58.804596 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277153389 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:30:10.836578 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58420672 ecr 2277153389], length 0
09:30:10.836601 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277165421 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:30:35.668812 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58426880 ecr 2277165421], length 0
09:30:35.668827 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 0, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277190253 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:30:48.436329 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331925739, win 1265, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277203020 ecr 58414552], length 0
09:30:48.586141 IP alb.443 > envoy.61682: Flags [.], seq 331925739:331927163, ack 1670, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 58430109 ecr 2277203020], length 1424
09:30:48.586164 IP envoy.61682 > alb.443: Flags [.], ack 331927163, win 1270, options [nop,nop,TS val 2277203170 ecr 58430109], length 0
```

As soon as envoy started reading again, once the client had read the buffer down enough, a small (we guess partial http payload) response would arrive from nginx/ALB and then either envoy would Fin the connection or the ALB would.

We observed the following messages:

```
{"time": "2019-08-30 08:23:09.557", "level": "debug", "type": "client", "message": "[source/common/http/codec_client.cc:118] [C157] protocol error: http/1.1 protocol error: HPE_INVALID_EOF_STATE"}
{"time": "2019-08-30 08:23:09.557", "level": "debug", "type": "client", "message": "[source/common/http/codec_client.cc:82] [C157] disconnect. resetting 1 pending requests"}
```

Anyways, this is all a long winded way of saying: the large initial_stream_window_size for HTTP2 https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/api/envoy/api/v2/core/protocol.proto
seems to cause a rather hard to diagnose issue when combined with a slow client and an AWS ALB's default read_timeout.

We suspect this might also cause issues for defaults like nginx's http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#send_timeout which is 60 as well.

We would suggest to cover the most number of clients that the default be lowered to 16 MB, which is where we have ended up. :) Or at least we could help introduce some flags in the logs to explain the connection was finished due to a partial/corrupt HTTP response from Envoy's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

initial_stream_window_size is documented here https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/core/protocol.proto#envoy-api-field-core-http2protocoloptions-initial-connection-window-size and the relevant default size is here https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/api/envoy/api/v2/core/protocol.proto

```
  // `Initial stream-level flow-control window
  // <https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.6.9.2>`_ size. Valid values range from 65535
  // (2^16 - 1, HTTP/2 default) to 2147483647 (2^31 - 1, HTTP/2 maximum) and defaults to 268435456
  // (256 * 1024 * 1024).
```

We resolved this issue in two ways which can be used independently or together:

1. We raised the ALB timeout (or nginx if you are speaking to some other proxy type) from the default 60 to 300s+, during which time clients are more likely to read out enough data to cause Envoy's buffer to drop below a watermark needed to trigger further read events and thus reset the cluster/upstreams read timeout.
2. We lowered the initial_stream_window_size to something more sane like

```
            http2_protocol_options:
              initial_stream_window_size: 16777216
```

The added benefit here is we experience more consistent and lower memory usage, while we have not observed any performance degradation even on high speed clients.